# Guardar en matriz

Tags: c

¿Cómo hago para que se guarde letra por letra de la nueva palabra en una matriz?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int  i=0,j,arr[26]={},temp;     
    char  s[10],arr1[10],*p;      
    printf("Enter the string\n");
    scanf("%s",s);
    p=s;
    while(*p!='\0')
         {
            temp=((*p)>92)?(*p)-'a':(*p)-'A';
            if(arr[temp]==0)              
              {
                 arr1[i]=temp+'a';
                 arr[temp]=1;         
                 i++;
              }
            p++;                          
         }
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
           printf("%c",arr1[j]);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En una matriz? Matriz de cuanto? 1x0, 2x5... de que dimensiones quieres la matriz? Y cuál es la finalidad de esta línea **temp=((*p)>92)?(*p)-'a':(*p)-'A';**.

Comment: Las tareas del cole son para hacerlas... o al menos especifica dudas más concretas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que no has especificado nada, se me ocurrió hacer el ejemplo más vago y simple en C. Tus variables tienen nombres tan raros que dudo que tú mismo puedas entender lo que hace tu programa, ten buena practica y haz tu código legible, y sigue practicando.
Te recomiendo leer el libro de la biblia del C, "el lenguaje C por kernighan y ritchie"

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    //insertas las filas y las columnas de la matriz
    int filas, columnas;
    scanf("%d %d", &filas, &columnas);

    //creas la matriz de caracteres
    char arreglo[filas][columnas], letra;

    //insertamos letras(caracteres) no palabras
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
            printf("Ingresa una letra: \n");
            scanf("%c", &letra);
            arreglo[i][j] = letra
        }
    }

    //imprimimos la matriz
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
            printf("%c", arreglo[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```